# EC2 public DNS set up from localhost

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a local web site running on `localhost:8080` with my local machine.

And I want to make this local website available to public audience. How do I do this with `EC2` or `Elastic Beanstalk`. I tried to host this website within `EC2` instance and tried to connect through its public DNS but cannot connect. Please let me know how to set up the public DNS for website that is running as localhost inside `EC2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some guides on how to deploy Python based web applications on Elastic Beanstalk.

Django example:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

Flask example:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html

You can also use your other framework.

Getting Started guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.Walkthrough.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to connect via the public IP address to port 8080 on the EC2 instance, it sounds to me like you need to change the security group for the EC2 instance to allow you to connect to port 8080. Security groups are basically firewall rules for the EC2 instance.

Take a look at the AWS documentation for EC2 Security groups: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

If you have a security group that allows you IP to connect to port 8080 on your EC2 instance, perhaps this is a web server configuration issue where the webserver is not listening on the network interface used by the public IP address.